# Correct way of passing dataframe to ray

Tags: pandas, ray

I am trying to do the simplest thing with Ray, but no matter what I do it just never releases memory and fails.

The usage case is simply
read parquet files to DF -> pass to pool of actors -> make changes to DF -> return DF

```
class Main_func:
    def calculate(self,data):

    #do some things with the DF

    return df.copy(deep=True) <- one of many attempts to fix the problem, but didnt work


cpus = 24
actors = []
for _ in range(cpus):
    actors.append(Main_func.remote())

from ray.util import ActorPool
pool = ActorPool(actors)

import os
arr = os.listdir("/some/files")



def to_ray():
    try:
        filename = arr.pop(0)
        pf = ParquetFile("/some/files/" + filename)
        df = pf.to_pandas()
        pool.submit(lambda a,v:a.calculate.remote(v),df.copy(deep=True)
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)

for _ in range(cpus):
    to_ray()

while(True):
    res = pool.get_next_unordered()
    write('./temp/' + random_filename, res,compression='GZIP')   
    del res
    to_ray()
```

I have tried other ways of doing the same thing, manually submitting rather than the map command, but whatever i do it always locks memory and fails after a few 100 dataframes.

Answer (score 1):

Does each task needs to preserve state among different files? Ray has tasks abstraction that should simplify things:

```py
import ray

ray.init()

@ray.remote
def read_and_write(path):
    df = pd.read_parquet(path)
    ... do things
    df.to_parquet("./temp/...")

import os
arr = os.listdir("/some/files")
results = ray.get([read_and_write.remote(path) for path in arr])
```